# How to set android background image

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Guys here I have some code that sets the background color to white but however I want to change the code to set an image that I have but keep the same ID of the color so that it is picked up by the rest of the code and I dont have to change it everywhere.

```
<color name="editor_background_color">#ffffffff</color>
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Well I said it clear I want instead of color to be an image with an ID editor_background_color. I think it is not hard to understand what I said.

Comment: You can search Stack Overflow where many examples of adding a background image to and Android app already exist. As for retaining the color of your background image, what more is there to be said than "assign the color, but don't use the value to set the background?" If this answer doesn't meet your needs, perhaps your question may be clear to you, but to the non-telepaths attempting to help you, it may indeed be unclear.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get an image from an XML file you should first of all insert your image in the Drawable folder naming it as,in your case,"editor_background"  of your project and get it from your source code:

```
@drawable/editor_background
```

for example,if you want to set the background of your activity:

```
android:background="@drawable/editor_background"
```

hope this post was useful!

Comment: android:background="@drawable/editor_background" i know how to do this but my application picks this color name editor_background_color and sets it from there. I want to make a drawable image background with the same name editor_background_color so that I dont have to change it. Is this really hard to understand?

Comment: So rename your image in editor_background_color,even if it's not autoexplicative! and your could put the image in the color folder, so you don't have to rename everything,even if this is not good programming. th best solution is to modify the code i suppose.. i understood what you asked, but in this case i don't see much solutions..